# NodeJS getting Promise result from Console

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, promise, google-chrome-devtools

If I want to get the result of a Promise from my node-testing console, how would I do that?

eg.

```
let promise = new Promise(() => {
  console.log('my promise');
}
promise.then(() => { console.log('resolved') })
// returns a Promise {<pending>}

await promise.then(() => { console.log('resolved') })
// still returns just a Promise

(async () => {
    await promise
})()
// still returns ... just a Promise
```

Ultimately I'm trying to test promise results (database queries) from my node console at a breakpoint, and I just keep getting Promises returned.

---

**UPDATE -** I guess this is more complicated than I thought. Because know one has been able to answer.

I understand how to get the results of a promise in a regular environment. I'm talking about getting results at a breakpoint while debugging a Node application. To connect to the console I'm referring to please follow these directions:
https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27

From the console in DevTools, promises keep returning Promise {}. I do not know if it is possible to get the value of the promise, but if anyone knows either way please let me know.

Comment: The one with `await` not wrapped in an extra async function shouldn’t have given you a promise. It should either have been the value or a syntax error. Can you show a screenshot of it? (Also, assigning to a variable with `let x; promise.then(y => { x = y; })` or logging with `promise.then(console.log)` are good in a pinch.)

Comment: (these all assume that your real promise *ever* resolves. your example one doesn’t.)

Comment: I changed the promise to have "resolve('my promise')" and it still just returns "Promise {<pending>}"

Comment: What exactly is "*my node-testing console*"? Are you using the node REPL?

Comment: @Bergi if you follow here it shows you what I mean:
https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27

Comment: @webbyweb Ah, ok, if you had written "debugging console" instead of "testing console" I guess it would have been clearer :-) But no, if you are doing any asynchronous calls *while being paused on a breakpoint* then I doubt you can ever get back the asynchronous result, as the event loop is paused and cannot advance to the next tick. But imo you shouldn't be calling async code from a breakpoint anyway - why would you do that?

Comment: Ah I see makes sense. I am just trying to make DB queries while testing. I found a workaround though where I have an async console up using Node's ("--experimental-repl-await") flag where I can be making DB queries. But thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments I guess it is impossible to get asynchronous call results while at a breakpoint in JavaScript.

If anyone comes here and wants a way to be able to make DB queries from the Node console (REPL) like I was looking for,  I'd recommend going here:

https://medium.com/@vemarav/build-rails-like-console-in-nodejs-repl-2459fb5d387b

Answer (score 1):

when you create a promise object you should use this syntax

```
var promiseObj = new Promise(executor);
```

the executor is a function with this signature

```
function(resolutionFunc, rejectionFunc){
    // typically, some asynchronous operation.
}
```

When we go back to your specific example, you can define it as

```
let promise = new Promise( resolve => {
    resolve("my promise")
})
```

**Note** I havent added the reject function

then you can do

```
promise.then(value => console.log(value))
```

you can find a detailed description [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: your explanation is correct as promise is resolved immediately in this case, but there are different behaviour on node console and browser console. Node console still says Promise is pending while browser console says it is resolved.

Comment: ^thanks. Exactly I understand that the promise would work correctly if I was using it in an app, or in the browser console. But not in the console while debugging an application (ie. at a breakpoint)

here shows how to connect: https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27

Answer (score 0):

The position of your breakpoints matters, and the behavior will be the same in the Node.js debugger and the browser debugger.

In the following I use labels like `<b1>` to identify breakpoint positions.

```js
1.  const p1 = new Promise((resolve) => <b1> resolve('result 1'))
2.  <b2>
3.  const p2 = p1.then(() => <b3> 'result 2')
4.  <b4>
```

At `<b1>`, `p1` will be undeclared because the executor function runs synchronously, and the variable declaration process has not yet completed.

At `<b2>`, `p1` will be a fulfilled promise (`Promise {<fulfilled>: "result 1"}`), resolved with the value `'result 1'` because resolve was called in the executor function.

**The next breakpoint to be hit will be `<b4>`.** Note: *not* `<b3>`.

At `<b4>`, `p2` will be a pending promise (`Promise {<pending>}`) **because the promise has been configured with a `.then` that has not yet had the opportunity to run.** `.then` callbacks are run on asynchronous microtasks to give the programmer the opportunity to configure a promise chain ahead of its execution. After all, promises *are* designed to be used with asynchronous behavior.

On the next available microtask, `<b3>` will be hit as the `.then` callback is run. At `<b3>` the values of `p1` and `p2` remain unchanged. `p1` was fulfilled earlier and will not change. The state of `p2` is unchanged because the `.then` it was configured with has not yet completed running.

In order to observe `p2` in its fulfilled state, you need to add a breakpoint to an extension of the promise chain.

```js
let p1 = new Promise((resolve) => resolve('result 1'))
const p2 = p1.then(() => 'result 2')
p2.then(() => {
  // here `p2` === `Promise {<resolved>: "result 2"}`
  console.log(p2)
})
```

Comment: As I've explained before. I understand this is how promises would work in a regular environment. Where I'm trying to get the results of a promise are at a breakpoint while debugging my Node application.

So the console I would be running in would be here if you follow to this environment:
https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27

I just tried your code, and once again it returns "Promise {pending} "

Comment: Whether you are running in the node debugger, or in the browser, the behavior will be the same. The positioning of your breakpoints is important. As I say above: "_note how you always need to keep your code in the chain of callback functions. This is because the asynchronous flow of control runs through these callbacks._"